# color fill in column series in flex conditional

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I want to create a daily build chart with 1 column as 1 build, 1 build will have 3 series for eg feature 1, feature 2, feature 3. Now i need to fill the color of the series dynamically based on the feature is pass or fail. 
for eg if in a particular build feature 1: Pass, feature 2: Fail, feature 3:Fail then the color sequence of the column will be green, red, red.
Kindly help me how to implement this logic and where? (if in fillfunction)

Comment: Is there a reason this can't be implemented using code?  Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here ? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c52.html